# how to use the evaluation function with determined last row in VBA

Tags: range, match, row, evaluation

I am using the evaulation function in combination with match function. The first aim is to incorperate the variable which containts the number of the"last row" which is the row that contains the first blank cell, here declared as NextRow into the evaluation function. I have been trying the two variants as depicted below. Somehow it doesn't seems to work. I am sure I have done somewhere a mistake in the combination in the "E1:E & NextRow &" part.
My second question is whether it it possible to stop the search of the evaluation function when it hits its first full match? Meaning, it stops as soon as it find the letters A,B,C in the columns E,F,G and goes no further from then on.

```
Function E01(……..)
Set NextRow=Worksheets(“Roh“).cells(cells.Rows.count,1).End(xlup).Offset(1,0)

1.) RicRow= Worksheets(“Roh“).Evaluate("match(“““ & A & ““ & B & ““ & C & “““, E1:E & NextRow & F1:F 
& NextRow & G1:G & NextRow, 0)“)

2.) RicRow= Worksheets(“Roh“).Evaluate("match(“““ & A & ““ & B & ““ & C & “““, E1:E & 
NextRow.Columns("E“) & F1:F & NextRow.Columns("F“) &G 1: & NextRow.Columns("G“) , 0)“)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is below:

```
RicRow= Worksheets(“Roh“).Evaluate("match(“““ & A & ““ & B & ““ & C & “““, E1:E" & NextRow.Row &" & F1:F" & NextRow & " & G1:G" & NextRow &", 0)“)
```